# android Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar on lollipop

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I create new project (api14-api21) in android studio 1.02. I change 1 line, from:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

in styles.xml to:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

and i have this:

```
Process: pl.xxx.myapplication, PID: 5433
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{pl.xxx.myapplication/pl.xxx.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
```

It's possible to fix this? I would like to use Theme.Holo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not going to use `appcompat-v7` and `Theme.AppCompat`, you need to:

- inherit from `Activity` (or, really, anything other than `ActionBarActivity`)
- change any menu resources to use `android:` instead of `app:` for things like `android:showAsAction`

in addition to changing your theme, as you did.

To be safe, and to reduce the size of your APK, you can also get rid of the dependency on `appcompat-v7` from your `app` module's `build.gradle` file.