# android setting not changes

Tags: android, android-activity, r.java-file, android-settings

am using android studio, and i set minimum sdk version as API14:Android 4.0, but the new project and the compiler set the version support to Lollipop by default.

i try to change that, but at the next time and when am trying to compile is show error.

The **Highlighted folder in the image** generated automatically, why is this generats.
[image]

while i run the module or an app, it shows only like this[image]

Why am not getting the navigation keys and the querty keyboards like in eclipse Emulator.
When i compile at the first time i got that all, but after that from the second time am not getting that and all. whats the problem in it?

And why the main activity by default extends the ActionBarActivity
[image]
What is the setting do i have to change it, to get all the main activity extends activity for the new project and going to create.

these are all the changes happens after my first project i created, after these changes am not getting that R.java file

Explain the problems and Doubt i have, and guide the instructions..

Answer (score 1):

This is actually several questions; let me try to give a quick answer to each one.

1. "Default version support set to Lollipop" -- There's not enough
   detail here for me to make a recommendation. Are you perhaps setting
   the target sdk rather than the min sdk? The target sdk should always
   be set to the most recent version unless you have very specific
   reasons to do otherwise.
2. The extra folder you highlighted is where your test code is created. Unlike Eclipse, Android Studio does not have an option to
   not create a test framework. If you don't want tests, then delete
   this folder from the project.
3. It sounds like you've updated to the latest emulator, which no longer shows a "physical" keyboard if keyboard input is enabled.
   Instead, if you've created an AVD that supports a physical keyboard,
   the new emulator accepts input from your computer keyboard. I'd
   imagine that this decision was made in order to simplify the
   emulator and save screen space; the number of Android devices that
   ship with a physical keyboard is very small.
4. ActionBarActivity is the default base class for most of the built-in app templates because it's what Google wants to encourage developers to use. You're free to change the generated code to make MainActivity extend Activity instead.
5. Regarding R.java, Android Studio does not show generated files in the Project tool window by default. There's a small dropdown on the top of the Project tool window. If you change it from "Android" to "Project" then it will show all of the files in the project. R.java is in app/build/source/r//. Or you can use the class browser
   to view R.java. Press Ctrl+N to bring up the class
   navigation window, type R, and then hit Enter. The generated R.java
   file should appear, along with a warning that it's generated and
   shouldn't be edited.

   In general Android Studio does a pretty good job of rebuilding R.java when its dependencies change. If you need to force R.java to be rebuilt, you can do it via the Gradle tool window. Under "all tasks" there should be a list of tasks for your project. (You might need to open up some items in the tree view to get to the task list.) Double click on "GenerateXXXXSources" where "XXXX" is the build flavor you want to generate for (e.g. Debug, Release). This will regenerate R.java.

Comment: "because it's what most apps want" -- you're welcome to your opinion on that one. "If you want the generated MainActivity to extend Activity, then choose "Fullscreen Activity" during the project creation process" -- while it is possible it has `Activity` as the base class as a side effect, that's not really what that template is for. "Android Studio does not show generated files in the Project view" -- it does in the `build/` directory. So, `build/generated/source/r/` will lead to `R.java`, with directories based upon build variant(?).

Answer (score 1):

> And why the main activity by default extends the ActionBarActivity

That's what most of the stock templates in Android Studio use, for better or for worse.

> What is the setting do i have to change it, to get all the main activity extends activity for the new project and going to create.

There is no "setting" for this that I am aware of. Either:

- do not have Android Studio create the new activity for you, and create it yourself, or
- use a template that happens to not require `ActionBarActivity`, such as Mr. Lewis' suggestion of the "Fullscreen Activity", then fix up the other things that the chosen template does that you do not want, or
- [edit your project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28287787/115145) to remove `appcompat-v7` and things that it references, like `ActionBarActivity`